# Removing dotted underline from linked img

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am tinker with a wordpress site and have gone and thrown in some of my own raw html via their virtual editor. The outcome is what I wanted, but there seems to be a blue dotted underline underneath each image. How can I remove this? I tried everything from text-decoration: none; to outline:0

Here is a working link to the site http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css in style.css

```
.logoLinks a
{
 border: none;
}
```

this css overwrite your old css

style.css line 42

```
a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #3156A3;
}
```

Comment: You guys are in your own way right. This was the best solution for me. Thanks. I accept this as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
a img { border:0; }
```

or

```
.logoLinks a img { border:0; }
```

?

I saw that you have border-bottom declared in all your a's. So try overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

The under line is from

```
style.css:42
a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #3156A3;
}
```

just remove it or add a style to override it.