# I want to remove a link style from an img in it

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm working on a project where the client can create his own content, so he added an image (`<img>`) in a link (`<a>`) that I styled.

I'm trying not to use style in this image, but it's not working because the `img` is inside the `<a>` tag, so it is inheriting the style from `a`. 
Maybe you know another way to do it with SASS?

- I tried to unstyle the `img` that's inside `a` but without success.
- I also tried this: [Removing dotted underline from linked img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669271/removing-dotted-underline-from-linked-img)

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/Gabrielsen/pen/rNNaEvb

And a snippet:

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-bottom-width: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom: solid .2rem green;
}

a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 5rem;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.5rem 0 green;
  border-color: green;
}

// I want remove the style of the a from the img but I can't do this because her parent is the link and he have the style : 
a img,
a:hover img,
a:focus img,
a:active img {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/heXu37IbDvVy6Qbo1wbPjNvi6Ys=/0x0:712x423/1200x800/filters:focal(385x120:497x232)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/55531035/Screen_Shot_2017_06_30_at_3.17.00_PM.0.png" alt="Juste... Pickle-rick"> My
  link from the hell
</a>
```

No error messages, just my tears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to go for the image width instead of the height and set `height: auto;` then use the [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0px;
  height: 1rem;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);/* 100% - (width of the image)*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-bottom-width: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom: solid .2rem green;
}
a img {
  height: auto;
  width: 5rem;
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.5rem 0 green;
  border-color: green;
}

a img,
a:hover img,
a:focus img,
a:active img {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/heXu37IbDvVy6Qbo1wbPjNvi6Ys=/0x0:712x423/1200x800/filters:focal(385x120:497x232)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/55531035/Screen_Shot_2017_06_30_at_3.17.00_PM.0.png" alt="Juste... Pickle-rick"> My
  link from the hell
</a>
```

You can wrap the text in a [span element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a span{
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-bottom: solid .2rem green;
}

a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 5rem;
}

a:hover span,
a:focus span,
a:active span{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.5rem 0 green;
  border-color: green;
}
  
a img,
a:hover img,
a:focus img,
a:active img {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/heXu37IbDvVy6Qbo1wbPjNvi6Ys=/0x0:712x423/1200x800/filters:focal(385x120:497x232)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/55531035/Screen_Shot_2017_06_30_at_3.17.00_PM.0.png" alt="Juste... Pickle-rick"> <span>My link from the hell</span>
</a>
```

or you can use the [Aspect ratio (image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image))

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0px;
  height: 1rem;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem*1.5);/* 100% - (height of the image)x1.5*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-bottom-width: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom: solid .2rem green;
}
a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 5rem;
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.5rem 0 green;
  border-color: green;
}

a img,
a:hover img,
a:focus img,
a:active img {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/heXu37IbDvVy6Qbo1wbPjNvi6Ys=/0x0:712x423/1200x800/filters:focal(385x120:497x232)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/55531035/Screen_Shot_2017_06_30_at_3.17.00_PM.0.png" alt="Juste... Pickle-rick"> My
  link from the hell
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your anchor link like so:

```
<a class="myLink" href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/heXu37IbDvVy6Qbo1wbPjNvi6Ys=/0x0:712x423/1200x800/filters:focal(385x120:497x232)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/55531035/Screen_Shot_2017_06_30_at_3.17.00_PM.0.png" alt="Juste... Pickle-rick"> My
  link from the hell
</a>
```

Then target that link with this CSS:

```
.myLink {
border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant make it unless image is positioned absolute or other way can add margin-bottom:-0.5rem; to image which hides border